# How does KeyedDecodingContainer implement decode<T>(_ type: T.Type, forKey key: KeyedDecodingContainer<K>.Key) throws -> T where T: Decodable

Tags: ios, swift, decoding, codable, decodable

I was experimenting with Decodable and couldn't figure out how the compiler synthesises a `decode(_ type: Decodable.Protocol, forKey key: CodingKey)` function for a specific `Decodable` instance (Such as a `Book`).

```
struct Book: Codable {
    var title: String
    var pages: Int
    var author: String
    var coauthor: String
}
struct Bookstore: Codable {
    var book: Book
    var owner: String
}
```

I tried to write a `decode(_:forKey:)` function on my own so I could get a better idea of how the compiler synthesises it but I was absolutely blanking. I started with overloading the `decode(_:forKey:)` function for `Book.Type` but that's as far as I got.

```
extension KeyedDecodingContainer {
    func decode(_ type: Book.Type, forKey key: CodingKey) throws -> Book {
         print("I am about to decode a Book from the data keyed by \(key.stringValue)")

         // I have no clue what to put here

    }
}
```

If someone can help me finish this implementation I'll be very grateful as it will help me understand the decoding process better.

Thanks in advance!

## Edit:

What I've tried so far:

```
extension KeyedDecodingContainer {
    func decode(_ type: Book.Type, forKey key: CodingKey) throws -> Book {
        print("I am about to decode a Book from the data keyed by \(key.stringValue)")

        let decoder = try self.superDecoder(forKey: key as! K)
        return try Book(from: decoder)
    }
}
```

This works but I have no clue what exactly `as! K` is doing nor do I know what `superDecoder(forKey:)` does. Also I'm not sure if using force-casting in this situation is considered risky. Is there a safer way to do this?

Comment: Are you talking about [this method](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/keyeddecodingcontainer/2921358-decode)?

Comment: @Sweeper Yes I am

Comment: After inspecting [Codable.swift](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/main/stdlib/public/core/Codable.swift), my understanding is that `KeyedDecodingContainer` does not directly implement this method (not in a meaningful way at least). Rather, each decoder (e.g. `JSONDecoder`) provides their own implementation of `KeyedDecodingContainerProtocol`, and the `KeyedDecodingContainer.decode` method calls _that implementation's_ `decode` method. TLDR, it depends on the decoder.

Comment: The not-very-meaningful implementation is on line 1755. You can see how it delegates the call.

Comment: @Sweeper So I shouldn't try to implement it on my own? How would you implement `decode(_ type: Book.Type, forKey key: CodingKey) throws -> Book` if you had to?

Comment: Why would you care about implementing this? Note that it would only work if Your Book object is not the root object and it is a property of a struct or a class.

Comment: @LeoDabus I had absolutely no reason to implement this. I was just curious

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you misunderstood something here, the compiler doesn't synthesise anything. `decode` is *generic*, with a generic type parameter `T` constrained to `Decodable`. This means that once it is declared, it will work on all types that conform to `Decodable`. There isn't a separate implementation of it generated for `Book`. It's all the same implementation, just with different `T`s. The signature that you should be focusing on is:

```
func decode<T>(_ type: T.Type, forKey key: KeyedDecodingContainer<K>.Key) throws -> T where T : Decodable
```

How is it implemented? The [source code](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/main/stdlib/public/core/Codable.swift#L1755) says:

```
public func decode<T: Decodable>(
    _ type: T.Type,
    forKey key: Key
) throws -> T {
    return try _box.decode(T.self, forKey: key)
}
```

So a question such as "How would you implement [this method] if you had to?" is not very meaningful because the method has already been implemented, and you would not have to implement it yourself.

Now obviously that implementation isn't very useful in understanding how it works. It just delegates the call to something else. The call eventually gets delegated to `KeyedDecodingContainerProtocol`, and which implementation of `KeyedDecodingContainerProtocol` that is, depends on the decoder that you are using. For example, `JSONDecoder` would use a different decoding container from `PropertyListDecoder`.

Now the question becomes, how is the `decode` method in `KeyedDecodingContainerProtocol` implemented? Well, as we've established, it depends on the decoder. The JSON decoder would do some JSON-specific things, and the property list decoder would do some property list-specific things, but eventually they would probably call [`T.init(from:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/decodable/2894081-init) to get an instance of `T`. `KeyedDecodingContainerProtocol.decode` ***is* something you can implement yourself. You need to implement this if you are writing your own decoder.** `T.init(from:)` **is also something you should implement, if you want your codable object to be decoded in a custom way.**

I can't find the source code of `JSONDecoder`, so here's an open source XML decoder that you can explore: https://github.com/ShawnMoore/XMLParsing

[This](https://github.com/ShawnMoore/XMLParsing/blob/master/Sources/XMLParsing/Decoder/XMLKeyedDecodingContainer.swift#L294) is how they implemented `KeyedDecodingContainerProtocol.decode`. This calls `unbox`, which calls `T.init(from:)` [here](https://github.com/ShawnMoore/XMLParsing/blob/master/Sources/XMLParsing/Decoder/XMLDecoder.swift#L816).